# Is there an $h$ such that $h = f/g$ is measurable, yet one of $f$, $g$, or neither are measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I was trying to find an $h$ such that $h = f/g$ is measurable, yet one of $f$, $g$, or neither are measurable. Is it perfectly fine to choose $f^{-1}(D)$ such that $D$ is non-measurable and similarly for $g$ so that in total $h$ is just maps to $0$, thus making $h$ measurable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $g$ be any non-measurable function which does not take the value $0$, and let $f$ be the constant $0$ function (which is measurable). Then $h=\frac{f}{g}=0$ is measurable.

Similarly, let $g$ be any non-measurable function which does not take the value $0$, and let $f=g$. Then $h=\frac{f}{g}=$ the constant $1$ function is measurable.

Comment: Is it possible to use similar arguments regarding integrable and non-integrable functions?